# Design pattern on navigating between the activities in android

Tags: android

**Hello**

[image: fig]

*I want to know how this concept is implemented in android*

- Navigation in this application takes place like this::

> Activity1- -- to- -  -> Activity 2- -to - -.>Activity 3 - - to - ->
>   Activity2

**But on doing  this ::**

*I pass the data from*

> Activity1 - - > Activity 2- -> I do not pass the data from Activity2 -
>   - > Activity3

**Now**

> If I navigate back to Activity2- - from - - Activity3

- The application closes because Activity2 is expecting the data which
  is not present in Activity3
- How can I overcome this, how can I preserve the state(even data) of
  activity 2 before navigating back from Activity3

**Cycle has to be ::**

> Activity1- -- to- -  -> Activity 2- -to - -.>Activity 3 - - to - ->
>   Activity2

---

- How to achieve this?
- What concepts do i need to look for

I hope i am clear with my description

Answer (score 0):

I think you are starting Activity2 again when navigating back to Activity2 from Activity3 which is wrong approch. You do not need to start Activity2 again. Just press back button from Activity3 your Activity2 which was in stack will be on foreground again and it will not call onCreate method again

Answer (score 0):

1. An activity is fully responsible for saving its state in `onPause()` and restoring it in `onCreate()`. Same is true for a Fragment as well.
2. If an activity 2 has requests Activity 3 to do something using `startActivityForResult()`, then, A will receive those results in its `onActivityResult()`, when Activity 3 finishes.
3. All new started activities build up as a task stack. When a new activity is finished, older activity just below it takes screen.

Android makes sure these methods are called in proper order.

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of the already posted answers:
The android-lifecycle preserves your activities if you don't re-create / destroy them. But make no mistake, android does not guarantee that the data will be there once you get back (still it normally is, but the garbage collector might remove stuff etc.) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

If however we are missing something and you are unsure on how to actually save data when an acticity is removed from the stack you might consider looking into the persistency mechanisms (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#SavingPersistentState). Especially for your input data (forms etc.) I quote the doc section on that matter:

> When an activity's onPause() method is called, it should commit to the
>   backing content provider or file any changes the user has made. This
>   ensures that those changes will be seen by any other activity that is
>   about to run. You will probably want to commit your data even more
>   aggressively at key times during your activity's lifecycle: for
>   example before starting a new activity, before finishing your own
>   activity, when the user switches between input fields, etc.